# Using Apollo Client Cache vs. Custom Redux Reducer

Tags: apollo, react-apollo

From React-Apollo Docs: **Updating  the Store**

> Apollo performs two important core tasks: Executing queries and
>   mutations, and caching the results.

Currently, in my App, I'm using Apollo to execute Queries and Mutations only.

The results of my queries and mutations are dispatched to a custom Redux reducer which my client then reads (writes, renders) from.

Are there distinct disadvantages of this current approach over using the Apollo Client's internal Redux store appropriately? (beyond writing additional code for the custom Redux store)

I care about disadvantages related to Design and Performance, favoring Design at the moment - with concern for if this pattern effectively "locks in" substandard performance, with future migration to the Apollo Store untenable for a medium sized application.

Thank you very much.